Paramagnetism in coordination complexes
A complex is classified as paramagnetic or diamagnetic based on the electronic configuration of the central atom/ion. Should the properties (para/dia) of surrounding ligands also affect the nature of the complex?  For example, a $\mathrm{d^6d^2sp^3}$ complex of $\ce{Fe}$ would be called diamagnetic. Will it still be called diamagnetic if one of the ligand is, let's say, paramagnetic superoxide ion ($\ce{O_2^-}$)?

A paramagetic molecule, such as O2 or NO, has one or more un-paired electrons so you can work this out for your complex.

No, it will be considered paramagnetic if the ligand is superoxide.
In most cases, the ligands are diamagnetic, that is why we directly check the central atom configuration without bothering about the ligand.

This answer would really profit from a deeper explanation. Is almost only a comment.
